# How do I account for colspan when parsing a table row using Nokogiri?

Tags: arrays, html-table, ruby-on-rails-5, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri with Rails 5.  Given a row from an HTML table, e.g.

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
```

I currently use this code to extract the table cell data as an array ...

```
row_values = row.css('td, th').map{|str| str.text }
                                          .map{|str| str.gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, ' ').gsub(/\A\p{Space}+|\p{Space}+\z/, '') }.join("\t")
```

in which "row" is my table row.  mY question is, how do I adjust the above so that if a table cell contains a colspan attribute, I would add extra blank elements into my array for each additional row occupied by the colspan?  So for instance, if my row were

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td colspan="2">2</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
```

My array would be

```
["1", "2", "", "3"]
```

Notice I have an extra "" in there because the second table cell has a "colspan" equal to 2.  If it were "3", I would have two extra ""s in my array, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to add the empty cells:

```
doc.search('[colspan]').each{|td| td.after '<td></td>' * (td['colspan'].to_i - 1)}
```

Now you can do it the way you did before